# What does the format specifiers "%02x " and "%3o " do in this code?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

While searching for the meaning of the statement of K&R C Exercise 7-2 I foun this answer to the K&R C Exercise 7.2 on https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_7:Exercise_2

The Exercise asks to

> Write a program that will print arbitrary input in a sensible way. As a minimum, it should print non-graphic characters in octal or hexadecimal according to local custom, and break long text lines.

Also I am unable to understand the meaning of sentence of the exercise, specifically the part "As a minimum, it should print non-graphic characters in octal or hexadecimal according to local custom".

What does this exercise 7-2 asks for? Please explain the meaning of the statement of exercise.

The code below uses format specifiers "%02x " and "%3o " are used at the end of the code to print non-printable characters but what exactly this format specifiers do to Non-Printables?

```
 else
    {
      if(textrun > 0 || binaryrun + width >= split)
      {
        printf("\nBinary stream: ");
        textrun = 0;
        binaryrun = 15;
      }
      printf(format, ch);
      binaryrun += width;
    }
```

Rest of the code break long lines into smaller ones and print all printable characters as it is.

The Complete Program is as below:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define OCTAL        8
    #define HEXADECIMAL 16


    void ProcessArgs(int argc, char *argv[], int *output)
    {
      int i = 0;
      while(argc > 1)
      {
        --argc;
        if(argv[argc][0] == '-')
        {
          i = 1;
          while(argv[argc][i] != '\0')
          {
            if(argv[argc][i] == 'o')
            {
              *output = OCTAL;
            }
            else if(argv[argc][i] == 'x')
            {
              *output = HEXADECIMAL;
            }
            else
            {
              /* Quietly ignore unknown switches, because we don't want to
              * interfere with the program's output. Later on in the
              * chapter, the delights of fprintf(stderr, "yadayadayada\n")
              * are revealed, just too late for this exercise.
              */
            }
          ++i;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    int can_print(int ch)
    {
      char *printable = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 !\"#%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?[\\]^_{|}~\t\f\v\r\n";

      char *s;
      int found = 0;

      for(s = printable; !found && *s; s++)
      {
        if(*s == ch)
        {
          found = 1;
        }
      }

      return found;
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      int split = 80;
      int output = HEXADECIMAL;
      int ch;
      int textrun = 0;
      int binaryrun = 0;
      char *format;
      int width = 0;

      ProcessArgs(argc, argv, &output);

      if(output == HEXADECIMAL)
      {
        format = "%02X ";
        width = 4;
      }
      else
      {
        format = "%3o ";
        width = 4;
      }

      while((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
      {
        if(can_print(ch))
        {
          if(binaryrun > 0)
          {
            putchar('\n');
            binaryrun = 0;
            textrun = 0;
          }
          putchar(ch);
          ++textrun;
          if(ch == '\n')
          {
            textrun = 0;
          }

          if(textrun == split)
          {
            putchar('\n');
            textrun = 0;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          if(textrun > 0 || binaryrun + width >= split)
          {
            printf("\nBinary stream: ");
            textrun = 0;
            binaryrun = 15;
          }
          printf(format, ch);
          binaryrun += width;
        }
      }

      putchar('\n');

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yes.. I've read about %o and %x (and about %02x). They print the i/p integer into octal or hexDec format (with 0 padding if width is less than 2). My main hurdle is in the understanding the purpose of putting these specifiers to print invisible characters. Which non-graphic or non-printable characters I can i/p and how? I know that from 0x00 to 0x20 are the invisibles ASCII Chars. Also I am not able to understand the statement of exercise precisely except that it asks to break long text lines at fixed length.

Comment: Next up, read up on the character classification functions in `ctype.h`. Or just look at the `can_print()` function in the code you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have found by yourself what "%02x " and "%03o " mean. That is good!

So your question boils down to "What are non-printable characters?" and "How are they printed with the mentioned formats?"

---

A non-printable character is defined (in the source shown) by the string `printable` in function `can_print()`. All characters not in this string are deliberately defined to be non-printable. *We can reason about the selection, but this is out of scope here. Another note: " " and "\t\f\v\r\n" are in this set of printable characters and have a value of <= 0x20 in ASCII.*

BTW, the standard library has `isprint()` that checks for printability.

---

As you seem to know each character is encoded as an assigned value. This value can be interpreted as you like, as a character, as a number, as an instruction, as a colour, as a bit pattern, anything. Actually all digital computers are just working on bit patterns, it's up to the interpretation what they mean.

So a non-printable character can be interpreted as an `int` number, and this is what happens by `printf()` with the mentioned format. Let's say that the character read is '\b', known as backspace. *(Note: It is not in `printable`.)* In ASCII this character is encoded as 0x08. So the output will be "08 " and "010 ", respectively.

You might like to change the program in such way that **all** characters are considered non-printable. Then you'll see all characters output as hex or octal.

Comment: Ok, go it! In short, the program asks user to print ASCII of non-printable chars in base 8 and base 16.. Am I interpreting it correctly right?
I was confused with determining the precise aim of the program.